# Get textarea value in servlet automatically without button click when value changes

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I want to get the textarea value in servlet whenever the textarea value changes. My page automatically refreshes every 30 secs. So i want the textarea value to go into servlet every 30 seconds automatically without button click.
Below is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />  


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x,y;  
x=41.689844;  

var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(x,-74.044874),
    destination = new google.maps.LatLng(42.2569387,-71.0043555),

    service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

var str1,str2,str3,str4;

function showlocation(){

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback1);


}

function rel(){
     location.reload(true);


}
function showlocation2(){

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback2);
}

function callback1(position){
   // document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
   // document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;

   /* var str = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br>' +
                  'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br>' +
                  'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp     + '<br>\r\n' ;
        document.getElementById('result').value += str;
    */

    str1=position.coords.latitude;
    str2=position.coords.longitude;
   // document.getElementById('result1').value += str1;
   // document.getElementById('result2').value += str2;

    document.getElementById('result1').value = str1;
    document.getElementById('result2').value = str2; 

    document.getElementById('originatt').value = ".";
    document.getElementById('destatt').value = ".";
    document.getElementById('distatt').value = ".";

    document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML ="Trip Recording has started"+"<br>"+"Click Get Origin Address";
}


function callback2(position){
  //document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML=position.coords.latitude;
   //document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML=position.coords.longitude;

   /* var str = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br>' +
                  'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br>' +
                  'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp     + '<br>\r\n' ;
        document.getElementById('result').value += str;
    */
    str3=position.coords.latitude;
    str4=position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('result3').value += str3;
    document.getElementById('result4').value += str4;
    document.getElementById('originatt').value = ".";
    document.getElementById('destatt').value = ".";
    document.getElementById('distatt').value = ".";


    document.getElementById('message1').innerHTML ="Trip Recording has stopped"+"<br>"+"Click to Get Destination Address";

}

service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, 
    callback
);

function callback(response, status) {
    var orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
        dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
        dist = document.getElementById("dist");




    if(status=="OK") {
        orig.value = response.destinationAddresses[0];
        dest.value = response.originAddresses[0];
        dist.value = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
    } else {
        alert("Error: " + status);
    }
}

function delay(ms) {
   ms += new Date().getTime();
   while (new Date() < ms){}
}

$("myform").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="img1">
    <img src="images/home/logo.jpg"  style="width:80%;">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    <form name="myform" action="TripRecorder" method="POST">
        <h4>   Click Start to record Origin and Stop to record Destination </h4>

<!--<span id="latitude" name="latit" hidden> </span>

 <span id="longitude" hidden> </span>
<br>-->


 <input type="button" name="start" class="st1" id="st" value="Start Trip" onclick="showlocation()"/> 


<br><br/>   
    <span id="message1" name="msg1"> </span>
</br></br>  




     <input id="originatt" type="text"  value="<%=request.getAttribute("origin5")%>"  ><br><br>

     <textarea id="result1"  name="res1" value="str1" cols="20" rows="1" ></textarea> <br> <br/>
      <textarea id="result2" name="res2" value="str2" cols="20" rows="1" ></textarea>
      <input class="one" id="s1" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Get Origin Address"  /> <br> <br/>

     <!-- <input class="one" id="s1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  /> <br> <br/> -->


<input type="submit" name="Submit" > <br> 
    </form>
     <br>

            <input type="button" value="Back to Submission Page" name="back" onclick="document.location.href='submission.jsp'" /> <br> <br/>
        <h5>Check distance using Google Maps</h5>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3929.1219514911336!2d76.32904011409968!3d10.006784275664728!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3b08729de9da66b7%3A0x3ede9e0d7ae9f2fa!2sIGA+TECH+Industrial+Electronics+Pvt+Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1456591588301" width="100" height="100" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <br>  
         </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.setTimeout(function() {

  repeat();

}, 1);


    function repeat(){

   document.getElementById("st").click();

    }



function showvalue(){
 //var someValue = $('#lat span').text();
 var div = document.getElementById("test");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
  alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
 }

function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }

    document.getElementById('submit1').onclick = function() {
        setTimeout(submitForm, 3000); 
    };


 </script>
```

My servlet doPost method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       // processRequest(request, response);
        String str1=request.getParameter("res1");
        String str2=request.getParameter("res2");
        System.out.println("coord="+str1+"/"+str2);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("navigator_1.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: i dont think 30 sec would make user to wait for more time, instead write onkeyup funciton

Comment: Hi @SundarBons could you provide me with some sample code.I am really stuck here!!!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup - try this example from w3school, I hope it will be helpful

Comment: @SundarBons but in my program the user does not enter any input. The value in textarea is populated automatically.Okeyup is only for key input right?

Comment: I tried it @SundarBons it didnt work function myFunction() {
    alert('Hi');
} and then i added onkeyup to the textarea it didnt work

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/vowulit/1 - I have created a sample program that will dynamically change value and pick its value

Comment: @SundarBons this really helps but still it is not getting the value in servlet.I need the code where the value in textarea goes into the servlet automatically or even if the value goes into a db in jsp that is also fine

Comment: @SundarBons Could you atleast get value from another textarea element  into autochanger element instead of autoincrementing.that way i could utilize this in my program but anyways you have been of great help here.Your insight and knowledge is amazing.

Comment: @SundarBons when i am trying to move the textarea value to another textarea then also i am getting an error var textArea = document.getElementById("result3");
var textArea1 = document.getElementById("result1");
//skip below
String text = textArea1.getText();
//a = Integer.parseInt(text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your jsp.... give id to your form and include your textarea inside form if you don't want to include it in your form you can hide it so that it is not visible and doesn't require any space on your page.

```
window.setInterval(function(){

submit();/// call your function here

}, 30000);
<script language="javascript">
function submit(){
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```